# Uploadify uploadLimit issue

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I use `uploadify` plugin for uploading files.

But when I use

```
jQuery('#video_thumb1').uploadify('settings','uploadLimit','4');
```

to change the limit count, I get an error.

I cannot resolve this problem, whats this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#file_upload_1").uploadify({
    height:30,
    swf: 'http://www.uploadify.com/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    uploader:'http://www.uploadify.com/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    width : 120,
    uploadLimit: 4
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kN3TN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery('#video_thumb1').uploadify({
   'uploadLimit' : '4' // Or change to whatever number is appropriate.
});
```

Comment: Almost.. `'uploadLimit' : '1'`